# GDB Core Analysis of a thread core dump

Tags: gdb

For some reason, the generated core file is only a core from a thread that is part of the main application.

When I load it with the binary that actualy crashed, I get

```
BFD: Warning: core is truncated: expected core file size >= 40919040, found: 61440.
```

How can I tell gdb that this is a thread from that binary?

Answer (score 3):

> For some reason, the generated core file is only a core from a thread that is part of the main application.

Whatever led you to conclude that? That conclusion is most likely wrong.

> BFD: Warning: core is truncated: expected core file size >= 40919040, found: 61440.

This message means exactly what it says: your `core` file should have been `40919040` bytes in size, but isn't.

The most likely reasons:

- you had `ulimit -c` set to 15 (too low)
- you had run out of disk space
- you have copied only part of the actual core (e.g. by hitting Control-C, or getting network disconnected during transfer)

Comment: In the systemd File I have, LimitCORE=infinity, so the ulimit is not low. There are 700 MB available on the disk where this is written. The core was copied completely. However, it looks like a to small thread stack was responsible for the Core. Maybe this is the reason that only a part was dumped